# Referential integrity for mysql

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, myisam

I am currently maintaining a rather large office web-application. I recently became aware that via various developer-tools within web-browsers that values of select-boxes can easily be modified by a user (among other things). On the server side I do validation if the the posted data is numerical or not (for drop-downs), but don't actually check if the value exists in a database table, for example I have a dropdown box for salutation ('mr','ms','mrs','Mr/ms') etc. which correspond with a numerical values.

Currently I use Mysql's Myisam tables which don't offer foreign keys referential integrity, so I am thinking about moving to Innodb, yet this posses the following issue:

If I want to apply referential integrity (to insure valid ID's are inserted), it would mean I'd have to index all columns (if using integrity checks) that do not necessarily need to be indexed for performance issues at all (e.g. a salutation dropdown). If a very large database client-table has say 10 simular dropdowns (e.g. clientgroup, no. of employees, country-region etc) it would seem an overkill to index every linked table.

My questions:

1) when using referential integrity, do columns really need to be indexed also?

2) are there other practical solutions I may be overlooking? (e.g. use a separate query for every dropdown-list to see if the value exists in a table?)

3) How do other web-applications deal with such issues?

Help Appreciated!

thanks
Patrick

Answer (score 1):

You only have to index the fields used in the foreign key relationships, and recent version of mysql do this automatically for you anyways. It's not "overkill". it's actually an optimization.

Consider that anytime you update/delete/insert a record, the foreign tables have to be checked for matching records - without the indexes, those checks could be glacially slow.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your quick reply :-) 
My believe is that MyIsam table do not perform such check, you can basically insert insert any value that is designated as 'foreign key'.

It is also my understanding that indexing should be applied sparsely; only when necessary to boost performance, with columns that result in a high cardinality.

Comment: yes, that's true. myisam parses/accepts foreign key declarations, but they're basically silently ignored and definitely NOT applied. and no, the rule of thumb for indexes is to apply them to any field used in a where/join/order or other "test the value" type situation.

Answer (score 1):

1. InnoDB automatically creates an index when you define a foreign key. If an index on that column already exists, InnoDB uses it instead of creating a new index.

   As @MarcB mentioned in his answer, InnoDB uses these indexes to make referential integrity checks more efficient during some types of data changes.  These changes include updating or deleting values in the parent table, and cascading operations.
2. You could use the [`ENUM` data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/enum.html) to restrict a column to a fixed set of values.  But `ENUM` [has some disadvantages](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/) too.
3. Some web developers eschew foreign keys.  To provide the same data integrity assurances, they have to write application code for every such case.  So if you like to write and test lots of repetitive code, unnecessarily duplicating features the RDBMS already provides more efficiently, then go ahead!  :-)

   Most developers who don't use foreign keys don't write those extra checks either.  They just don't have data integrity enforcement.  I.e. they have sacrificed *quality*.

PS: I do recommend switching to InnoDB, and referential integrity is just one of the reasons to do so.  Basically, if you want a database that supports [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID), InnoDB supports all aspects of that and MyISAM supports none.